# A function similar to v() of igraph in network package in R

Tags: r, vertices

I'm trying to plot a network object, I want to have the nodes colored based on a character attribute, when using an Igraph object, I did this:

```
plot(g, vertex.col = my_palette(as.factor(V(g)$attribute)))
```

but I don't know how to do this with a network object.

Answer (score 0):

One approach with `network` is to use `set.network.attribute` and add an attribute for color. Then in your `plot` statement use `vertex.col` to set the vertices to the attribute colors.

```
library("network")

set.seed(123)

g <- network.initialize(6)

add.edge(g,1,2)
add.edge(g,1,3)
add.edge(g,1,4)
add.edge(g,3,6)
add.edge(g,4,5)

set.network.attribute(g, "color", c("red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue", "black"))

plot(g, label = network.vertex.names(g), vertex.col = get.network.attribute(g, "color"))
```

**Plot**

[image: network plot with colors by attribute]